# HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL, Trying to receive incoming calls

Tags: java, servlets, twilio

I'm following the tutorials on Twilio to learn how to receive inbound calls. I keep running into the following error when running the servlet on tomcat in Eclipse.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnT2c.png)

I am testing the code for the following tutorial.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.twilio.twiml.voice.Say;
import com.twilio.twiml.TwiMLException;
import com.twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet("/voice")
public class IncomingCallServlet extends HttpServlet {
  // Handle HTTP POST to /voice
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Create a TwiML builder object
    VoiceResponse twiml = new VoiceResponse.Builder()
        .say(new Say.Builder("Hello world!")
              .voice(Say.Voice.ALICE)
              .build())
        .build();

    // Render TwiML as XML
    response.setContentType("text/xml");

    try {
      response.getWriter().print(twiml.toXml());
    } catch (TwiMLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }



  }
}
```

I have created a TestServlet to check if the tomcat server is working, and it is. However, when I try to run this servlet in the way it doesnt work.

Here is the structure.

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjWiC.png)

Here is the web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>TestServlet</display-name>
    <description></description>
    <servlet-class>neelr.TestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>IncomingCallServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>IncomingCallServlet</display-name>
    <description></description>
    <servlet-class>neelr.IncomingCallServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/TestServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>IncomingCallServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/IncomingCallServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am theorizing it has something to do with the url, but I'm not sure. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: As your servlet says, it only handles POST requests. You are sending it a GET request.

Comment: you need to use some rest client like postman and fire same request, browser only supports get requests from url. As rightly said by @tgdavies its a post request but you are sending a get request from browser, this is the issue